# JQuery Slide Down Error with Late Binding Event

Tags: jquery

I'm getting this error "**TypeError: f.handler.apply is not a function**" when I apply the following script to my view (this error is from the JQuery 2.1.3 library itself):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#crystal-container').hover('.thumbnail',
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(240); //.fadeIn(250)

    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(240,function(){$ (this).stop( true, true )}); //.fadeOut(205) and stop hover
    }
);
});
```

This exact script (without the late binding identifier #crystal-container) works fine on another view file where I am trying to have a transparent window slide down over an image, but when I try to use this on images that I'm loading via AJAX it gives me this error.  Any ideas why?

The transparent window does slide down, but it's happening on all images on the page when it should just be happening on the specific image the mouse is hovering on.  Once the window slides down I get this error message and the rest of the code ceases to fire.

Comment: I don't see an example of hover() in the docs that takes a selector as the first argument.  Only the one or two functions.

Comment: Check my answer it will sure work

Comment: If he's loading children after the fact, your solution does not handle for those.  It seems like he's trying to do a version of a delegate.

Comment: error given in question itself told half of the issue. didn't you check

Comment: "Calling $(selector).hover(handlerInOut) is shorthand for:  this doesn't mean I can use a selector as I have it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That didn't work either but the conversation gave me an idea.  I wrapped the hover function in a late binding mouseover and it works.  I'm not sure if this is a great solution but it does work.   Thanks for the help!

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#crystal-container').on('mouseover', '.thumbnail', function(){
    $('.thumbnail').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(240); //.fadeIn(250)

    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(240,function(){$ (this).stop( true, true )}); //.fadeOut(205) and stop hover
    }
);
});
});
```

Comment: Not the best solution as it rebinds hover on every mouseover.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can try this as your answer :

Here is updated code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#crystal-container').on('mouseover', '.thumbnail', function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(240); //.fadeIn(250)
  });


  $('#crystal-container').on('mouseout', '.thumbnail', function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(240,function(){$ (this).stop( true, true )}); //.fadeOut(205) and stop hover

  });
});
```

This will sure work.

Comment: yeah, this doesn't work because the event doesn't get bound to the .thumbnail class this way after the ajax call

Comment: so do you have element comes from  ajax call?

Comment: yes...the '.thumbnail' class gets created with an ajax call

Comment: can you provide fiddle

Comment: or live url to check the issue

Comment: I didn't downvote.  I'm a newbie don't think I can vote;)

Comment: i have update my answer, please check it. it may be use full, it you like you can upvote

Answer (score 0):

The following uses delegates similar to what your wanting I believe.  However it's sliding is probably not what you want, but you get the idea.

```js
$(function() {
            $('#crystal-container').on('mouseenter', '.thumbnail', function() {
                var $caption = $(this).find('.caption');
                $caption.slideDown(240);
            }).on('mouseout', '.thumbnail', function() {
                var $caption = $(this).find('.caption');
                $caption.slideUp(240,function(){$ (this).stop( true, true )});
            });

            //simulate records being created after the binding
            $('#crystal-container').append($('.thumbnail').eq(0).clone().prop('outerHTML'));
        });
```

```css
.thumbnail {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #888;
    min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="crystal-container">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
      Blah1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
      Blah2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution and Bhavins new solution seem to both work ..better than previously but as you say the sliding is not what I want because it slides back up immediately and the whole point of the sliding is for the user to be able to read something when they mouseover the image.  The hover allows this to happen correctly.